# Send POST data on redirect with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Basically what I want to do is send `POST` data when I change the `window.location`, as if a user has submitted a form and it went to a new page. I need to do it this way because I need to pass along a hidden URL, and I can’t simply place it in the URL as a `GET` for cosmetic reasons.

This is what I have at the moment, but it doesn’t send any POST data.

```
if(user has not voted) {

    window.location = 'http://example.com/vote/' + Username;

}
```

I know that you can send `POST` data with `jQuery.post()`, but I need it to be sent with the new `window.location`.

So to recap, I need to send `api_url` value via `POST` to `http://example.com/vote/`, while sending the user to the same page at the same time.

---

**For future reference, I ended up doing the following**:

```
if(user has not voted) {

    $('#inset_form').html('<form action="http://example.com/vote/' + Username + '" name="vote" method="post" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="api_url" value="' + Return_URL + '" /></form>');

    document.forms['vote'].submit();

}
```

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Construct and fill out a hidden `method=POST action="http://example.com/vote"` form and submit it, rather than using `window.location` at all.

Comment: Is there any way to do this using an nested object? Say I need the data `{"a":{"b":"c"}}` passed along. Is there a way to that with a form?

Comment: @AakilFernandes You can always `JSON.stringify` your object and put the resulting string into a form field. You **can't** send an arbitrary POST content type that a form wouldn't otherwise support.

Comment: but what if there is a `<form>` already? what can be done since `form` tags cannot be nested??

Comment: @Malky.Kid do it as you would normally with a form, for example _(using @AakilFernandes' data)_ you'd create `<input type="hidden" name="a[b]" value="c">` within the form where "b" is a property of "a" with value "c".

Answer (score 259):

per @Kevin-Reid's answer, here's an alternative to the "I ended up doing the following" example that avoids needing to name and then lookup the form object again by constructing the form specifically (using jQuery)..

```
var url = 'http://example.com/vote/' + Username;
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="text" name="api_url" value="' + Return_URL + '" />' +
  '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: I prefer this method over Kevin's method because you don't have to add a form to the html. The reason I wanted to do this was that I had a form already and nested another form inside of it. For some reason my main form decided to stop where the other began, ignoring all of the inputs that followed. I know this shouldn't happen, but there you go.

The above method is nice when you want to 'redirect' with POST data from a piece of JS. Although I can't really shake feeling dirty when I do it this way ;).

Comment: Note that `$(form)` on the last line is redundant.

Comment: Just to add, current approach would display form for a fraction of a second on the "UI" before submitting. Just to make it perfect, add 'style' attribute to the form tag with value 'display: none;' .

Comment: As long as there's no style on the form element (borders, margins and whatnot) you can use `type="hidden"` instead.

Comment: @Joe Depends how the method is called.  If called via a hyperlink instead of a submit button `$(form).submit();` is very valid.  However `$('body').append(form);` is redundant as the variable `form` is being submitted.

Comment: It's what I needed in few rows of code :D thank you!!

Comment: I found that $('body').append(form); was very necessary in IE browsers!

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker I mean var form = $(...) gives you a jQuery instance. You don't need to re-wrap it in $(). form.submit() is enough.

Comment: @Mosselman, I felt the same way.  Worked like a charm, but same dirty feeling.  Would be nice if there was an ajax call that mimicked a form being submitted.

Comment: ugly but useful, thx. Better avoid

Comment: I am unable to access this form in a spring controller to which the form is posted. Any clue of how can I get the form contents? Please.

Comment: Yuck. Super wish this was just in jQuery core.

Answer (score 62):

Here's a simple small function that can be applied anywhere as long as you're using jQuery.

```
var redirect = 'http://www.website.com/page?id=23231';
$.redirectPost(redirect, {x: 'example', y: 'abc'});

// jquery extend function
$.extend(
{
    redirectPost: function(location, args)
    {
        var form = '';
        $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
            value = value.split('"').join('\"')
            form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
        });
        $('<form action="' + location + '" method="POST">' + form + '</form>').appendTo($(document.body)).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note this will only work for data if it is one level deep like the example. For data such as `{x: {z:'example'}, y: 'abc'}` you'll have to `JSON.stringify` and then decode in your server side code.

Comment: @AakilFernandes where would be Json.stringify?

Comment: @angel in modern browsers, there should be a global JSON object

Comment: Apparently this function requires "jquery.redirect.min.js plugin"

Answer (score 40):

Here is a method, which does not use jQuery.
I used it to create a bookmarklet, which checks the current page on w3-html-validator.

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.action='http://validator.w3.org/check';
f.method='POST';
f.target='_blank';

var i=document.createElement('input');
i.type='hidden';
i.name='fragment';
i.value='<!DOCTYPE html>'+document.documentElement.outerHTML;
f.appendChild(i);

document.body.appendChild(f);
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 38):

If you are using jQuery, there is a [redirect plugin](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js) that works with the POST or GET method. It creates a form with hidden inputs and submits it for you. An example of how to get it working:

```
$.redirect('demo.php', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});
```

**Note:** You can pass the method types GET or POST as an optional third parameter; POST is the default.

Comment: This plugin worked great for me, thanks.  I just copied and pasted the whole class into my code and use the example you have to test it and it worked fine.  Now to include it properly...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, @Tom. For those who wants to pass CSRF token with POST (I use Laravel framework) add it to the data like this: $.redirect('demo.php', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2', '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'});. Have fun ;-)

Comment: Worked great, just a copy and paste, thank you!

Answer (score 23):

The answers here can be confusing so i will give you a sample code that i am working with.

To start with note that there is no POST parameter to java script windows.location function that you are referring to.

So you have to...

1. Dynamically make a form with a POST parameter.
2. Dynamically put a textbox or textboxes with your desired values to post
3. Invoke the submit form you dynamically created.

And for the example.

```
     //---------- make sure to link to your jQuery library ----//

<script type="text/javascript" >

    var form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    $(form).attr("action", "test2.php");
    $(form).attr("method", "POST");
    $(form).css("display", "none");

    var input_employee_name = $("<input>")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("name", "employee_name")
    .val("Peter" );
    $(form).append($(input_employee_name));


    var input_salary = $("<input>")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("name", "salary")
    .val("1000" );
    $(form).append($(input_salary));

    form.appendTo( document.body );
    $(form).submit();

</script>
```

If all is done well, you shall be redirected to test2.php and you can use POST to read passed values of employee_name and salary; that will be Peter and 1000 respectively.

On test2.php you can get your values thus.

```
$employee_name = $_POST['employee_name'];
$salary = $_POST['salary'];
```

Needless to say , make sure you sanitize your passed values.

Comment: good answer. this will help some people

Comment: You are a superstar. Saved my entire day :)

Comment: hello, what i cannot understand is, since this is a post request, how would the target url loads its respective page?

Comment: hey vigamage. when you do this the aim is not to display values in test2.php. Instead it is to procees the POST values. eg. Save employee name and salary onto a database.

Comment: This to me was the cleanest solution. The property chaining (along with some indentation) helps a lot with readability (and maintainability). Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Generic function to post any JavaScript object to the given URL.

```
function postAndRedirect(url, postData)
{
    var postFormStr = "<form method='POST' action='" + url + "'>\n";

    for (var key in postData)
    {
        if (postData.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            postFormStr += "<input type='hidden' name='" + key + "' value='" + postData[key] + "'></input>";
        }
    }

    postFormStr += "</form>";

    var formElement = $(postFormStr);

    $('body').append(formElement);
    $(formElement).submit();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is quite handy to use:

```
var myRedirect = function(redirectUrl, arg, value) {
  var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="'+ arg +'" value="' + value + '"></input>' + '</form>');
  $('body').append(form);
  $(form).submit();
};
```

then use it like:

```
myRedirect("/yourRedirectingUrl", "arg", "argValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myRedirect = function(redirectUrl) {
var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="parameter1" value="sample" />' +
'<input type="hidden" name="parameter2" value="Sample data 2" />' +
'</form>');
$('body').append(form);
$(form).submit();
};
```

Found code at http://www.prowebguru.com/2013/10/send-post-data-while-redirecting-with-jquery/

Going to try this and other suggestions for my work.

Is there any other way to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target` attribute to send form with redirect from iframe.
Your form open tag would be something like this:

```
method="post" action="http://some.url.com/form_action" target="_top"
```