# How can I pass data via POST and show as Pop UP

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I pass data to a aspx page, via POST and then open this page as a pop up ?

I'm trying use `$.post` method, but how can I open this filled page in a pop up ?

If I try something like this, will open the mypage.aspx without the data that I pass ?

```
$.post("..mypage.aspx", {datainfo : datainfo }, function (data) { window.open() }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: @EyalAr Put a form action with the page that I want, will open in the same window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is impossible , they way you are doing it !

the correct approach is

1)use jquery colorbox or thickbox and open 'mypage.aspx' in it.
2)on page load of 'mypage.aspx' get the data from parent page in to the mypage.aspx using javascript or session 
3)add a button in mypage.aspx(hide its visibility)
4)fire click event of the button using javascript and post the data.

hope it helps !