# “params” in @RequestMapping annotation not working Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to check the form parameter in my spring controller class but getting below error

Invalid request method: Request method 'POST' not supportedException-Message: Request method 'POST' not supportedRequest-Info-----

Current-Request-URL=http://sit-www.hm.com/view/checkout/submitCurrent-Request-URI=/view/checkout/submitForward-Request-Uri=/de/checkout/submitForward-Query-String=nullInclude-Request-Uri=nullInclude-Query-String=nullMethod=POSTRemoteAddr=193.234.233.229--------- Session info"

Java script code :

```
elements.formCheckout.append($('<input type="hidden" name="New-submit" />'));
```

Controller class in spring:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = ACTION_SUBMIT, method = POST, params = "New-submit")
    public ModelAndView submitOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute(PATH) CheckoutComponentDTO form, BindingResult result,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

I added param="New-submit" to check in controller class but it is showing

```
Invalid request method: Request method 'POST' not supportedException-Message.
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Java script code : elements.formCheckout.append($('<input type="hidden" name="New-submit" />'));

Comment: Are you submitting the form via javascript?

Comment: Yes..elements.formCheckout.append($('<input type="hidden" name="New-submit" />')) we are passing from java script and i have to check the name in my controller class before processing ...

Comment: You are sending `GET` request not `POST` that's why this error, For `POST` request data must be in the request body not through URL.

Comment: Can you tell me some example .So i can check.Thanks

Comment: Please include your HTML in question.

Answer (score 0):

As I think you are not using calling the method of type **POST** from javascript
here is the code to call post method from javascript.

[how to send data in POST method using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13678358/8357590)

Comment: Tried .but still facing same issue

Comment: Could you post the whole code of javascript.It will help to identify what the problem is getting