# Send POST data on redirect with Javascript/jQuery to a top level iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

This question refers to: [Send POST data on redirect with Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery/8390201?noredirect=1#comment28157938_8390201)

The solution for the problem was to generate a hidden form which is then submitted to handle the POST + redirect - however I will be generating the page in an iframe and redirecting the parent frame - is this possible with javascript?

edit: As is always the way came across the solution shortly after posting the question! =S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set target="_top" in the iframe's form tag. That tells the browser to load the response in the parent frame.