# perform post action by redirecting to the page using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, web

How to perform post action by redirecting to the page using jquery.I tried something like this

```
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: response.data.myUrl,
              data: JSON.stringify(response.data.myParam),
              dataType: "json"
         });
```

I need to redirect to the url posting data to it.But this isnt working out.Can anyone please help me.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8390201/569751

Comment: The problem is that my data is complete object and couldnt create an hidden input field for every single field.It has lot of values.Is there any other method to perform this?

Comment: perform post, on sucess callback do window.location for redirection?

Comment: @user2078883 If you `stringify` your object, it is simply one string that you can submit via a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize form fields into JSON and stringify the result.

```
        /**
         * Serialize form fields into JSON
         **/
        (function($){
        $.fn.serializeJSON = function(){
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function() {
                     if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                            }
                            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                        } else {
                            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                        } 
            });
            return o;
        }
        })(jQuery);
```

So you'll have one string with all fields, put it into an hidden field and submit the form:

```
myString= JSON.stringify($('#myForm').serializeJSON());
$("#myForm #myString").val(myString);
$("#myForm").attr("action", YOUR_URL);
$("#myForm").submit();
```

This is supposed to be the form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="myString" />
</form>
```