# Pass data from one page to another page using only Javascript without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to know that when we would like to transfer data from one page to another using Javascript and not refreshing the page, what are the steps (or to say the perfect step) to do so.

All of my efforts are futile, the code I used are not processing perfectly. Is there a way to strictly use a Javascript method and a post method and send data to another page without refreshing. The aspect that the page does not refresh is done, but the data is not getting transferred to another page.

Comment: Search Google for AJAX.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do? Could you post some of your code/what you've tried so far?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Local Storage or Session Storage provided by Javascript. It saves your data for later use. I use it on my project and so far so good.

Here's the link for the manual: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Hey Guys, Thanks alot i got my problem solved.. yess the data was successfully, transferred to the database. Yahoo, now i can move on to the next stage of the site. The Next step is now EMAIL Verification. i'll start tomorrow.