# passing the ajax response data to another page after ajax call on success

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have ajax call and pull the data and I want to send the response to next page in ajax success and get the data in drilldown.html

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "drilldown.php",
         data:data,
        success: function(response){
          window.location.href = 'drilldown.php'; // want to post the data this in redirection
      }
});
```

Comment: The only way I see this is by adding the response data as a query parameter to your URL

Comment: Is it possible in post call

Comment: Various options: POST-redirect (submit the form to the new url, not via ajax), localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie, URL parameters.

Comment: If your ajax url is the same as the location you want to redirect, why not go there directly? There seems to be a problem with your flow. You send an ajax request to drilldown, and then redirect the user to drilldown.

Comment: It is possible, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send POST data on redirect with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389646/send-post-data-on-redirect-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Also, you can't POST data to an HTML page. You would need a script, like PHP or Node.

Comment: I agree with @RomiHalasz, maybe rethink your flow?

Comment: @freedomn-m How do you run a PHP script inside an HTML file?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no server-side involved, you can save the data using 
[`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (check if browser compatibility is OK for you)

```js
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "drilldown.html",
         data:data,
        success: function(response){
          localStorage.setItem('myData', data);
          window.location.href = 'drilldown.html'; // want to post the data this in redirection
      }
});
```

On the `drilldown.html` page, you can read the data with JavaScript by

```js
var data = localStorage.getItem('myData');
```

There's also [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which will be cleaned up after browser restart.